# get files with DirectoryInfo in Virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, image, directoryinfo

I have a arrav string like this:

```
string[] imgList = new[] { "/Images/10000489Back20130827.jpg", "/Images/2F.jpg", "/Images/10000489Front20130827.jpg" };
```

that contain names of file, contained in an virtaul directory.

If this parameteres I assigned to an ImageUrl, the image is displayed. In the detail of the pages show the propertie like this:

```
src="/Images/1F.jpg"
```

But when I try to looking for the files in specific directory all the files and assigned to an ImageUrl rpoperties, the images it's not displayed. I note that the path retrieve complete, and not a reference of the virtaul directory

```
string path = "/Images"; ///Obtener el path virtual

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg");

imgList = files.Where(x => x.FullName.Contains(clientNumber)).Select(x => x.FullName).ToList().ToArray();
```

I retrieve this path:

```
src="C:/Images/1F.jpg"
```

How can I get only the virtual path with the name of the file using DirectoryInfo class?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string path = "/Images";
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it:

Instead to pass the full path:

```
x.FullName
```

I concatenate the virtual path with the file name.

```
path + x.Name
```

Example

```
imgList = files.Where(x => x.FullName.Contains(clientNumber)).Select(x => path + x.Name).ToList().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Show Image In Virtual Path Like (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Signature.png) : Its Working

#### I used Try Catch To Avoid Error

#### Cliend Side :

asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" />

#### Server Side :

try
        {

```
        Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Signature.png");
        Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Image1.Visible = true;

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
```